# sonarqube service file soon die / Active: inactive (dead)

Tags: linux, service, sonarqube

When I start the service, the program first turns and soon dies. What's the reason? Is there anything I can do?

=====

serivce file :

```
[Unit]
Description=sonarqube

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/src/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga2RA.png)

Comment: You should look at SonarQube log files.

Comment: How could I check the full log? @AntonioPetricca

Comment: Suddenly Error doesn't appear.. hummmm